# ¿Como añadir un registro a memoria enx86?

Tags: c, x86

Tengo el siguiente codigo en C:

```
#define N 10
int Matriz[N][N],i,suma;
for (i=0,suma=0;i<N;i++)
suma+=Matriz[i][2]
```

Y me piden que lo traduzca a `lenguaje ensamblador x86`.

El problema esta que solo dispongo de registros `%eax,%ebx,%ecx` y `%edx` asi que había pensado poner la variable `suma`en memoria para no tener usar un registro para guardar su valor pero desconozco que instrucción hace eso. Es decir, mi idea sería:

`movl $0, %ebx`

Y despues

> instrucion guarda contenido ebx en memoria y asi ebx la tengo libre y la puedo usar para calculos poseteriors

Comment: Para éste caso, el direccionamiento de memoria sería lo más complicado que podrías hacer, comparado con otras opciones como el manejo de la pila o una región en `DATA`. Considera que cada uno de los registros que mencionas tienen parte *Alta* y *Baja*, es decir tienes 8 subregistros.

Comment: Como sería eso? Ahora que lo mencionas recuerdo haber visto algo de registro high y low pero si te digo la verdad voy muy perdido en ensamblador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar los subregistros `X`, `H` y `L`.

Ej. Para `EBX`:

- `BX`: 16 bits de la parte alta de `EBX`.
- `BH`: 8 bits de la parte alta de la parte baja de `EBX`.
- `BL`: 8 bits de la parte baja de la parte baja de `EBX`.

Para `H`y `L` usa el sufijo byte:

```
movb $0, %bl
```